# If the decimal expansion of $a/b$ contains "$7143$" then $b>1250$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, fractions

I recently stumbled upon this really interesting problem:

> Suppose we have a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and we know that the decimal fraction of $\frac{a}{b}$ has the numerical sequence $7143$ somewhere in the decimal place. Show that $b > 1250 $.

This question is part of *der Bundeswettbewerb Mathematik 2015, zweite Rund*. The competition ended September 1st, 2015.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The trick is to realize $7\times0.7143=5.0001$.

First let's multiply by $10^n$ to shift the decimal to the right - hence for some integers $k$ and $n$ and real number $c\in[0,1)$ we can write

$$\frac{10^na}{b}=k+0.7143+0.0001c$$

Now multiply by our [magic number](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seven)!

$$7\times\frac{10^na}{b}=7k+5.0001+0.0007c$$

Hence

$$7(10^na-kb)-5b=(0.0001+0.0007c)b$$

The left hand side is an integer, so there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$m=(0.0001+0.0007c)b$$

Since $0\le c<1$, we have

$$0.0001 b\le m<0.0008b$$

Additionally, since $b\in\mathbb{N}$, we have 
$$0<0.0001b\le m$$
so because $m$ is an integer, $$1\le m<0.0008b$$
giving $1250<b$ as desired.

Comment: That's definitely the most elementary approach. :)

Comment: WOW! What a beautiful solution.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt  I was wondering if we can solve this by reverse proofing. That is, we start with assuming b is definitely greater than 1250 and arrive to a fraction with 7143 in decimal. Can that be done? I tried doing that way but was lost.

Comment: @MonK I'm not sure exactly what you mean. From that it sounds like you trying to prove the converse - which isn't in general true (not every number greater than $1250$ yields a fraction with $7143$ in the decimal, like $\frac{1}{10000}$).

Comment: Proof from the book :)

Comment: @Silenttiffy, ThomasAndrews: Thanks! I can't claim all the credit for this idea though - I had a conversation with user JimmyK4542 a couple years ago where he demonstrated that some numbers can be easily factored (by hand) if they are first $\textit{multiplied}$ (try factoring $142857$ vs. factoring $142857\times 7$ (you might recognize $0.142857$ as close to the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{7}$)).

Comment: Very nice proof but I fail to grasp how it could be generalized to a generic sequence of numbers. Also, can it only be used to prove that a given threshold is true, or can it also be used to find the _minimum_ value for b?

Comment: The method generalizes for any sequence of digits which has a (smallish) multiple which is near a (smallish multiple of a) power of $10$. So for example the same approach would work for $857143$ since $7\times857143=6000001$. The method can only be used to prove a threshold, but that is to be expected because we are using rather loose estimates (in the sense that we don't care what the following decimal places could be).

Answer (score 11):

First multiply a by a power of 10 such that 7143 comes right after the decimal point, and then subtract a multiple of b such that the decimal fraction starts with $0.7143$. The claim we need to prove is then that the interval $[0.7143,0.7144)$ does not contain any rational with a denominator $\le 1250$.

The continued fractions for $0.7143$ and $0.7144$ are $[0;1,2,1,1,1428]$ and $[0;1,2,1,1,178]$, so the continued fraction expansion for every number in this interval will have the form
$[0;1,2,1,1,n,\ldots]$ where $178\le n\le 1428$ and there may or may not be more terms after the $n$.

If we work out $[0;1,2,1,1,n]$ as an ordinary fraction we get $\frac{5n+3}{7n+4}$, which (being a continued fraction approximant) is always in lowest terms.

When $n>178$ the denominator of this is at least $7\cdot 179+4=1257$. Since the denominators of continued fraction approximants always increase, we get $b \ge 1257$.

On the other hand we might have $n=178$ if there is a term *after* $n$ in the continued fraction expansion. But the simplest fraction we can then make corresponds to $n=178.5$, which would make the next approximant $\frac{5\cdot 178.5+3}{7\cdot 178.5+4}=\frac{1791}{2507}$, also with a large denominator.

Comment: Oh, right. Yes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Actually I liked having the continued fractions written out in full in your answer (which I was too lazy to TeX), so I think you should undelete yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did not know that continued fractions can be used in such a way—that's great!

Answer (score 7):

By multiplying $a$ with a power of $10$ if necessary, we may assume that $7143$ occurs immediately after the decimal point, and by subtracting a multiple of $b$ from $a$ we may assume that in fact $\frac ab=0.7143\ldots$.
Then
$$ \frac57=0.7142857\ldots <\frac ab <0.7144 = \frac{893}{1250}$$
Hence the numerators of the difference fractions $\frac ab-\frac 57=\frac{7a-5b}{7b}$ and $\frac{893}{1250}-\frac ab=\frac{893b-1250a}{1250b}$ are positive integers, i.e.,
$$ \begin{align}7a-\hphantom{88}5b&\ge 1\\-1250a+893b&\ge1\end{align}$$
Then $1250$ times the first inequality plus $7$ times the second inequality eliminates $a$, which gives us
$$ (-5\cdot 1250+7\cdot 893) b\ge 1250+7,$$
i.e.,
$$ b\ge 1257.$$

By the way, $1257$ is the best bound since
$$\frac{5+893}{7+1250}=\frac{898}{1257}=0.714399363564\ldots$$